# ROS2: DDS RMW static discovery configuration

Tags: ros, ros2, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I was wondering if ROS2 has an easy option to setup static discovery for RTI Connext Pro for example.

https://github.com/ros2/rmw_connext

It seems that the discovery is dynamic. Is there a possibility to give a XML file or give a list of initial peers to connect to ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295494/ros2:-dds-rmw-static-discovery-configuration/) by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 527 on 2018-06-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lidor Shimoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/50376/lidor-shimoni/) on 2020-11-09**:
did you manage to set up static discovery? if you did can you please share your configuration files?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no ROS 2 way of doing static discovery or indicating to the underlying middleware that you want to do it. You might be able to configure the underlying middleware to do it with a configuration file or something, but that will be vendor specific.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3